# Any Spring PHP project?

Tags: java, php, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am coming from Java Spring background. I am big fan of various Spring modules like Spring Core, Spring Security, Spring MVC etc.

I would now like to implement a web project in PHP and also I would like to leverage features provided by Spring framework. Is it possible to expose Services (Service Oriented Architecture) on server side using Spring and PHP?

I read about this article http://www.cs.montana.edu/~tosun/phpvsjava.pdf wherein a lot of limitations of PHP mentioned w.r.t. Java. Do you suggest any alternatives for overcoming these limitations?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I read about this project as well - http://code.google.com/p/springphp/ but this is not being maintained anymore i.e. last checkin was during year 2007

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html). You get a lot of nice features like dependency injection that you are used to with Spring.

Hope that helps.